# Is it normal for dpkg / kernel update to hit 100%?

Tags: kernel, dpkg

I ran `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` today and my heart skipped a beat when Conky showed all 8 CPUs at 100% and temperature spiked to 88 degrees Celsius. It lasted at least a minute giving my slow hands time to copy and paste terminal screen line and take screen snapshot. The current terminal screen line showed:

```
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 4.8.11-040811-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.11-040811-generic
```

Is this normal behavior?

Conky screen below as reference:

[image: Kernel Update 100%]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks normal for parallel compilation job.

- `dkms` recompiles the dynamic modules (drivers) with each new kernel install

  To check for the drivers you have installed using DKMS, run

  ```
  dkms status
  ```
- 04x`cc1` instances of GNU C compiler appeared in the process list with high CPU usage (around 11/12.5=88%).

---

- Usually, you see the installation instructions from source (using `autotools`)

  ```
  ./configure
  make
  sudo make install
  ```

  but many users don't know that you can speed up the compilation for most packages. For example, with:

  ```
  make -j4
  ```

  Depending on how many CPU cores you have.
- Checking the `/usr/src/*/dkms.conf` files, WinEunuuchs2Unix (OP) could find the exact setup:

  ```
  MAKE[0]="'make' -j$(nproc) NV_EXCLUDE_BUILD_MODULES='' KERNEL_UNAME=${kernelver} IGNORE_XEN_PRESENCE=1 IGNORE_CC_MISMATCH=1 SYSSRC=$kernel_source_dir LD=/usr/bin/ld.bfd modules"
  ```

  `$(nproc)` which seems replaced by `8` in this case.

Comment: In what file would one place the `make -j4` line?

Comment: I see. I thought there was a `dpkg` file that could be updated since it was the one compiling the drivers in this  scenario.

Comment: of course dkms... so there should be a dkms setup / configuration file someplace where you can change `make` to `make -j4` probably.

Comment: I found my two `dkms.conf` files and the first one for nvidia has `CLEAN="make clean"` and `MAKE[0]="'make' -j$(nproc) NV_EXCLUDE_BUILD_MODULES='' KERNEL_UNAME=${kernelver} IGNORE_XEN_PRESENCE=1 IGNORE_CC_MISMATCH=1 SYSSRC=$kernel_source_dir LD=/usr/bin/ld.bfd modules"`. So it appears it is use `make -j8` already.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49268/discussion-between-user-dz-and-wineunuuchs2unix).